# Redux, Redux Toolkit how to wait until dispatch is finished

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

guys

Like in the subject is there a solution to wait until dispatch action is finished and then dispatch another?

Do I need thunk?

```
dispatch(someAction());
```

when `someAction` is finished dispatch `anotherAction()`

```
dispatch(anotherAction());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616697/6117565

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on the action. Normal non-thunk actions are synchronous, so in the next line after the `dispatch`, the first action will already be 100% handled.
If you are dispatching thunk actions there, you can either `await` or `.then(..)` the value that is returned by `dispatch`.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the idea of @phry.
I use redux-toolkit and have this as an example thunk:

```
export const EXAMPLE_THUNK = createAsyncThunk(
  "group/event/example_thunk",
  async () => {
    // Just resolves after 2 seconds.
    return await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  }
);
```

To dispatch another action after the first dispatch, you can simply await the first dispatch. In my example I updated the loading state.

*Although this example works, I am not 100% sure this is the best design pattern out there. Many examples I have seen is updating the state is some dispatch has been resolved! Personally I think this is a more clear way of writing my code*

```
 const handleChangeStatus = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await dispatch(EXAMPLE_THUNK())
    // Or dispatch something else. 
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: I did not think this would work because it gives a warning "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.". But it actually works. Thanks for the simple answer.